Detailed explanation of boiling
I have heard several explanations for why a liquid will boil when its vapor pressure equals the atmospheric pressure:
(1) The vapor pressure can be thought of as the pressure that the surface molecules exert against the atmosphere (?), when the atmospheric pressure is greater than the vapor pressure the surface molecules are essentially confined to the liquid, but once the vapor pressure equals the atmospheric pressure they can "push out" and escape.
I don't find this explanation convincing: Why is the vapor pressure equivalent to the pressure the surface molecules exert against the atmosphere? - I thought it was the pressure obtained when an equilibrium is reach between the gaseous and liquid phases. Also, wouldn't the molecules with sufficient energy to escape the liquid not just diffuse away rather than getting "pushed back" by the atmosphere (evaporation)?
(2) Fluctuations within the bulk of the liquid form bubbles of water vapor with internal pressure equal to the vapor pressure. When the atmospheric pressure exceeds the vapor pressure the bubbles cannot be maintained and collapse, otherwise the bubbles rise to the surface as they less dense than the liquid phase. This leads to the rapid transformation of water in the bulk liquid to gas - boiling.
In this case, why is the pressure within the bubble equal to the vapor presure? - the bubble is formed from a fluctuation meaning it is not in equilibrium with the bulk liquid. Furthermore, even if this is the case, in addition to the atmospheric pressure the hydrostatic pressure is also acting on the bubble (causing it to rise). Wouldn't the internal pressure have to balance this?
Could somebody provide a detailed explanation of what actually occurs during this process? It would be also be helpful if it could be made more quantitative. If this is too complicated for a single post, then a reference to a textbook explanation or paper would be sufficient.
